# PHP - How to get number array

Tags: php, xml

example output like :  0,1,2,3,4
how if want to get just number of array like that, thanks before

```
answers     {3}
answer      [5]
-> 0        {1}
            text    :   mengolah menjadi makanan terna
-> 1        {1}
            text    :   mengolah menjadi makanan terna
-> 2        {1}
            text    :   mengolah menjadi makanan terna
-> 3        {1}
            text    :   mengolah menjadi makanan terna
-> 4        {1}
            text    :   mengolah menjadi makanan terna
```

Comment: You will have to put a little more effort in making clear what it is you are doing and asking.

Comment: Your question is to unclear to answer. Please be more specific, add a test case, example input/ouput, your code...

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to be able to have the key in a variable while iterating the array, you can use a foreach that uses a variable for the key:

```
foreach($answers as $key=>$answer){
    echo $key; 
}
```

Output:

```
 01234
```

If you want a separate array with your keys, use array_keys:

```
$keys = array_keys($answers);
print_r($keys);
```

Output:

```
 Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 4
)
```

Check the PHP manual for info on [array_keys()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php).

Answer (score 0):

In PHP exist two types of arrays (https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

1. with numeric indexes(keys)
2. with sting indexes(keys)

If You need get only array keys you can use `array_keys` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys)

Example:

```php
<?php
    $my_array = array('apple', 'banana');
    print_r(array_keys($my_array));
?>
```

If you need get key and related value you can use foreach(https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Example:

```php
<?php
    $my_array = array('apple', 'banana');
    foreach($my_array as $key=>$value){
        echo('Key: '.$key.' has value'.$value.'<br>');
    }
?>
```

Little recommendation: If you need only display array or something like that use link to original array (symbol `&`) for value. If you don't use link to original array `foreach` will create copy your original array and iterate this copy. This case example below:

```php
<?php
    $my_array = array('apple', 'banana');
    foreach($my_array as $key=>&$value){
        echo('Key: '.$key.' has value'.$value.'<br>');
    }
?>
```